# WebHook Example Using java

Tags: payment-gateway, flutterwave

My webhook is getting called however the data am getting is scrambled. According to the documentation here https://flutterwavedevelopers.readme.io/docs/events-webhooks, am expecting a json message but instead, am getting this

`id=64883&txRef=HJDVXUSEMO&flwRef=N%2FA&orderRef=URF_1516263337305_8473935&paymentPlan=&createdAt=2018-01-18T08%3A15%3A37.000Z&amount=12.819223403930664&charged_amount=13.08&status=pending&IP=%3A%3Affff%3A127.0.0.1&currency=USD&customer%5Bid%5D=12569&customer%5Bphone%5D=&customer%5BfullName%5D=solodriver%20KESO4&customer%5Bcustomertoken%5D=&customer%5Bemail%5D=email%40solo.com&customer%5BcreatedAt%5D=2018-01-18T08%3A15%3A37.000Z&customer%5BupdatedAt%5D=2018-01-18T08%3A15%3A37.000Z&customer%5BdeletedAt%5D=&customer%5BAccountId%5D=957&entity%5Bcard6%5D=424242&entity%5Bcard_last4%5D=4242.`

Am using this code inside a HttpServlet

```
private static JSONObject getBody(HttpServletRequest request) throws 
IOException {

String jb = IOUtils.toString(request.getReader());
AppConstants.logger("JB:" + jb);
try 
    return HTTP.toJSONObject(jb);
catch (JSONException e) 
    // crash and burn
    throw new IOException("Error parsing JSON request string");
}
```

How do I get this format?

```
{
"id": "8368",
"txRef": "rave-checkout-1499791631",
"flwRef": "N/A",
"createdAt": "2017-07-11T16:47:39.000Z",
"amount": "9000",
"charged_amount": "9152.5",
"status": "pending",
"IP": "154.120.106.151",
"currency": "NGN",
"customer[id]": "380",
"customer[phone]": "",
"customer[fullName]": "Anonymous customer",
"customer[customertoken]": "",
"customer[email]": "user@example.com",
"customer[createdAt]": "2017-05-09T18:32:52.000Z",
"customer[updatedAt]": "2017-05-09T18:32:52.000Z",
"customer[deletedAt]": "customer[AccountId]",
"entity[card6]": "543889",
"entity[card_last4]": "0229"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation link you included:

> Webhook data is sent as form-urlencoded by default but you can
>   configure on your webhook settings page on the dashboard to send the
>   request as JSON instead.

So I would login to the dashboard and configure the setting there. I don't have a Flutterwave login, so don't know what the setting looks like

Answer (score 0):

@Matt Freake,
You are on point.

Another thing you can do is, on receipt of the event notification, do a URL decode and you should get your neat string

Comment: Your reply seems to be a comment. So you don't need to add answer. Use the "Add Comment" button. Thanks

Comment: @Matt Freake, You are on point.

Another thing you can do is, on receipt of the event notification, do a URL decode and you should get your neat string